# Lattices in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups

Can a lattice in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ have a normal abelian subgroup? It looks to me that it doesn't, but where can I read a proof?

Comment: In any semisimple connected Lie group with trivial center, any lattice is Zariski-dense. Hence any normal abelian subgroup $N$ should have its Zariski closure normal in the whole group, which forces $N=1$.

Comment: Migrating this from MO seems to show a certain trigger happiness.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different argument from that of Yves comes from Delzant's theorem SOUS-GROUPES DISTINGUÉS ET QUOTIENTS
DES GROUPES HYPERBOLIQUES, which states that the normal closure of a pair of noncommuting hyperbolic elements contains a free group. Showing that any normal subgroup contains hyperbolic elements is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

In any semisimple connected Lie group with trivial center, any lattice is Zariski-dense. Hence any normal abelian subgroup N should have its Zariski closure normal in the whole group, which forces $N=1$.